# Typo3 Fluid Templates How to add multiple templates

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, fluid-layout

I have a finished static HTML Template. I need to map it to typo3 so the content is dynamic. I followed following tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/FluidTemplates/Index.html

This works perfectly, but now I wonder how I can change the template per site? I made template for each site i.e Gallerie.html, Contact.html and they are linked to the same Layout as Header and Footer is always the same. 
How do I now tell the page About us to use the Gallerie.html?

My setup.typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page {
   typeNum = 0

   // Part 1: Fluid template section
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
   templateName = TEXT
   templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
   templateName.stdWrap.cObject {
      key.data = pagelayout

      pagets__default = TEXT
      pagets__default.value = Default

      default = TEXT
      default.value = Default

   }
   templateRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:eventmanagement/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
      1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
   }
   partialRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:eventmanagement/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
      1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
   }
   layoutRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:eventmanagement/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
      1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
   }
   dataProcessing {
      10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
      10 {
         levels = 1
         includeSpacer = 1
         as = mainnavigation
      }
   }
}
```

At the Moment it loads the Default.html Template from eventmanagement/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/ on every page. I created now a second Template called Gallerie.html in eventmanagement/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/ how do I add this now to the page Gallerie in the Backend?

Comment: Can you post your setup how you include the general template? The best is you edit your question, there you can format it too for better readability.

Comment: The person who voted down, should give a reason please. I think it's a very bad behavior voting down without any given reason, especially if the question is NOT obviously low quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's very useful to have for (nearly) every page another template but in general that's possible. Just consider that in the root-line always that template is used that is defined on the current level or - if not existing - that, that is found first while going up the root-line.

For every additional template you've to add a section inside this snippet from above:

```
templateName.stdWrap.cObject {  
  key.data = pagelayout

  pagets__default = TEXT
  pagets__default.value = Default

  default = TEXT
  default.value = Default

}
```

So including the option `about us` the snippet could look like this:

```
templateName.stdWrap.cObject {  
  key.data = pagelayout

  pagets__default = TEXT
  pagets__default.value = Default

  default = TEXT
  default.value = Default

  pagets__aboutus = TEXT
  pagets__aboutus.value = AboutUs

  aboutus = TEXT
  aboutus.value = AboutUs

}
```

Additional you still have to change the TCA probably to include the options in the drop-down-button.