# Typo3 Blog with Subtemplate

Tags: typo3

I am trying to set up the following structure:

```
Landing-Page (Root-Template)
--- Content Webpage 1
--- Content Webpage 2
------ Other Sub stuff
--- Blog (Blog-Template)
------ Blog stuff (apply Blog-Template)
--- 404, etc.
```

My problem with this is that if I am applying the blog template to my blog root, then my template is applied to all sites at the same level (so: Content Webpage 1 & 2, ...).

How can I prevent this and only assign my blog template to this site and lower?

P.S.: I am a beginner, so a bit of background would be nice if this is possible. I read a few of the Tutorials on docs.typo3.org, but that did not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an create a template-record on the page `Blog`, then only that page and subpages get that configuration. Else the default configuration is taken which is or has to be defined in the root-template.
You also could use [Conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference.html) in the root-template to check for the Blog-Page and assign the special template inside that condition. Assumed your Blog has the `pid` (Page-Id) 5 the condition would look like this:

```
... (other stuff before)

[PIDinRootline = 5]
    here you special template configuration
[global]

... (other stuff afterwards)
```

There is another option but there you need already advanced knowledge, as it's not explained too deep in my answer there (the TCA-part is missing): [how to add multiple fluid-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354030/typo3-fluid-templates-how-to-add-multiple-templates/52354635).

Comment: Would in your solution the root template styling be visible? The concrete case is that I would like to combine the Introduction package with a blog... Later I want also other (self-written) extensions with templates to have the same functionality as blog.

Comment: Also big thanks that alone really helped me a lot! I'll mark your answer as the correct after you answerd my comment :)

Comment: No my solution would only be visible in the blog, great that it helped you ;-)

Comment: If you choose the solution with the condition you can see the blog template in the TypoScript-Object Browser IF YOU CLICK IN THE BOTTOM TO SHOW THE CONFIGURATION WITH THE SPECIAL ACTIVATED CONDITION.
But this has no impact to the display of your site, the templates is still only working for the blog

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally got it to work like I desired.

Because the Blog-Template is a static Template I just assigend it to the main Template. Important was the order of the static Template includes.

1. `Fluid styled content`
2. `Bootstrap package`
3. `Typo3 Blog`
4. `Typo3 Blog Template`

The reason for that is that the `Typo3 Blog Template` needs the `Fluid styled content` and because my `Fluid styled content` include was the last one before, Typo3 threw me an error that it was not able to find some fluid elements.