# Typo3 Fluid Templates - How to set up different templates for different pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to build from scratch a website with typo3 9.5 and setting up different template files for different pages. How do I achieve this?

I'm following the tutorial from https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/TypoScriptConfiguration/Index.html and also tried the solution with no success provided at [Typo3 Fluid Templates How to add multiple templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354030/typo3-fluid-templates-how-to-add-multiple-templates)

Now all pages load the Default template and if I set the default cObject to Alternative, it loads the Alternative.html to all pages, even when the TCA at Typo3 is set correctly for each page:

- All Pages Back-end Layout to [Default]
- Contact set to [Alternative].

_

```
page = PAGE
page {
   typeNum = 0

   // Part 1: Fluid template section
   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
      templateName = TEXT
      templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
      templateName.stdWrap.cObject {
        key.data = pagelayout

        pagets__default = TEXT
        pagets__default.value = Default

        default = TEXT
        default.value = Default

        pagets__alternative = TEXT
        pagets__alternative.value = Alternative

        alternative = TEXT
        alternative.value = Alternative

      }


      templateRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:photo/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
      }
      partialRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:photo/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
      }
      layoutRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:photo/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
      }
      dataProcessing {
      10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
      10 {
         levels = 1
         includeSpacer = 1
         as = mainnavigation
         }
      }
   }
```

I want to use for instance a default.html template for all pages except contact page, which will have it's own template ( site_template/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/Alternative.html ).

Comment: So why don’t you create two partials, one for all the other pages and one only for contact and then on your default.html a condition which gets the uid and load the partial that you need?

Comment: Your proposal wouldn't let me use different back-end layouts and change the entire page structure, like the menu or the footer. In typo3 6.2 I used to build pages like this.

Comment: Why would it not? You can use whatever layout you want. On the partials you just define the col pos to where the data have to be saved. You can actually define which layout you would like to have, so the footer or header would be different as well...

Comment: So you're telling me to use partials as if they were templates? Well, that would be a fast solution. But still, I'm interested into learning how to use templates. I'm not conformed with just knowing a work-around. I'm really confused by the documentation as per older versions of typo3, I did everything very differently. Thanks for the idea anyway, is good to know!

Answer (score 1):

**First**:
you should use higher numbers for the paths to your templates.
The higher the number the higher the priority for overriding files with the same name.

**second**:
there is no field `pagelayout`. either use `layout` or better `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level` ([example configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630348/typo3-backend-layout-condition-in-typoscript/41631921#41631921) with the full usage of configuration for subpages).

Your key values (`pagets__default` and `pagets__alternative`) already hint to the usage of `backend_layout` (`pagets__*` is the usual key for backend layouts defined in page TSconfig).

Probably the example in the documentation needs some correction. (Pull-request commited)

Comment: Note: `pagelayout` is used in conjunction with `key.data` here (not `key.field`). `pagelayout` was introduced in typo3 7 and is basically the same as the typical backend_layout+backend_layout_next_level configuration people used before that. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/DataTypes/Index.html#pagelayout